# Building GRPC on Ubuntu 3.13.0-163-generic is failing to compile

Tags: linux, grpc

I am building GRPC in ubunut 3.13.0-163-generic from the source using make. I am getting the following error:

```
[GRPC]    Generating gRPC's protobuf service CC file from src/proto/grpc/channelz/channelz.proto
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc:794] CHECK failed: (scc->visit_status.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) == (SCCInfoBase::kRunning):
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  CHECK failed: (scc->visit_status.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) == (SCCInfoBase::kRunning):
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin killed by signal 6.
make: *** [/home/iadk/gokul/grcpcpp/grpc/gens/src/proto/grpc/channelz/channelz.grpc.pb.cc] Error 1
```

Why is GPRC failing to compile and how do I fix it?

Comment: Re-reun `make` with `make V=1` to get a verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 3.13.0-163-generic : That would be Ubuntu 14.04 . The default gcc 4.8 fails with GRPC. Download `gcc48-c++_4.8.4-2ubuntu14_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing ... The Ubuntu gcc 4.8 is patched with 163 patches. gcc48-c++_4.8.4-2ubuntu14 : None.

Install the compiler

```
$ sudo gdebi Downloads/gcc48-c++_4.8.4-2ubuntu14_amd64.deb
```

GRPC

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++ make autoconf libtool pkg-config libgflags-dev libgtest-dev

$ git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
$ cd grpc/
$ git submodule update --init
```

Edit the Makefile to gcc48, g++48 ... line 50 - 55 :

```
DEFAULT_CC = gcc48
DEFAULT_CXX = g++48
else
ifeq ($(HAS_GCC),true)
DEFAULT_CC = gcc48
DEFAULT_CXX = g++48
```

grpc/ :

```
$ make          // no errors
$ sudo make install
```

**Note** : `git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git` is important. The "curl" command mentioned in the original 
`grpc/BUILDING.md` can now provide a no-good result.